# tkinterdnd2 drag and drop not firing <<drop>> event

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

**I'm trying to figure out why a `<<drop>>` event isn't firing after dragging a file into a `tkinterdnd2` window.**

I am running the following script with a Python 3.10.2 interpreter:

```
import tkinterdnd2
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

window = tkinterdnd2.Tk()

def drop(event):
    path = event.data
    messagebox.showinfo("Success", f"Path: {event.data}")

window.drop_target_register(tkinterdnd2.DND_FILES)
window.dnd_bind("<<drop>>", drop)

window.mainloop()
```

**The Problem**

When I drag a file onto the screen, the cursor changes to a plus sign (+), but releasing the file does not fire the event.

**What I've Tried**

- Reinstalling tkinterdnd2 with pip
- [Right Click] and "Open With" the correct Python interpreter
- Adding a button to make sure that an event fires when clicked (It does)
- Changing the drop target to an entry box
- Restarting computer

**Question**

What am I doing wrong, or what can I do to make it right?

Comment: I think the event is actually named `<<Drop>>`.

Comment: @jasonharper you are a king. If you post it, I'll mark it as the answer.